# Safely removing and reclaiming Windows partition when Ubuntu was initially installed via Wubi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

I wish to reformat a `Windows 7` partition, reclaiming it for use under Ubuntu 14.04 already running on the machine. Windows is no longer needed.

The partition is mounted in Ubuntu and its files accessible to Ubuntu, but as mentioned no longer needed. How can I most safely go about this?

And also, Will this consequentially screw up the boot process?
To the point of boot - the machine started as Windows 7, then had Ubuntu 12 installed via Wubi, later Wubi was discarded of and the Ubuntu partition became a regular Ubuntu partition. The machine is still dual boot, but as mentioned Windows will no longer be needed.

Comment: Missed that it was no longer Wubi. See other duplicate mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I understand you correctly, you're dual-booted from a single partition (old fashiond after 13.04 or so). Does't really matter. The task is done the same.

1). Use the 'create recovery disk' tool every Windows system comes with (each manufacturer calls it something different).This will create a copy of the emergency restore partition already present on your drive. This will require 2-5 DVD's, depending on the manufacturer.

With these DVD's in hand, the task of erasing your drive and recreating your Win7 system to factory fresh state (down the road) becomes trivial.

2). Boot your DVD which contains your Ubuntu 14.04, and use it to install again. Then instruct the installer to wipe the drive and install using the entire drive.

After the install, set up Ubuntu with your old sign-on and then re-install any apps, then copy your personal files from a backup.

Hope that helps, have fun and good luck!

Comment: The idea was _not_ to wipe out the existing Ubuntu and re-install it. That would be the worst possible option...